# Error on merging dex

Tags: android

Unable to merge dex

> Error:Execution failed for task
>   ':app:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebug'.
>   java.lang.RuntimeException:
>   com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Unable to merge
>   dex

build.grandle file

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
//    buildToolsVersion "27.1.1"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.osan.user.askprediction"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 3
        versionName "1.1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    productFlavors {
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.0'
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    implementation('com.payumoney.sdkui:plug-n-play:1.0.0') {
        transitive = true;
        exclude module: 'payumoney-sdk'
    }
    implementation 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.19'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:15.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:15.0.0'
    implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.2.0'
    implementation 'com.payumoney.core:payumoney-sdk:7.0.1'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    implementation files('libs/okhttp-2.5.0.jar')
    implementation files('libs/okio-1.6.0.jar')
    implementation 'com.dinuscxj:circleprogressbar:1.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.paytm:pgplussdk:1.1.2'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.4.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.4.0'
}
configurations {
    all*.exclude group: 'com.android.volley'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: do `@Override
    protected void attachBaseContext(Context context) {
        super.attachBaseContext(context);
        MultiDex.install(this);

    }` in your application class

Comment: not working @nini0112

Comment: see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46267621/unable-to-merge-dex and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35890257/android-errorexecution-failed-for-task-apptransformclasseswithdexforrelease/45640607\

Comment: not work for me

Answer (score 1):

try

```
android {
    defaultConfig {
       multiDexEnabled true
    }
}
```

in your
**app/build.gradle**

Comment: alredy used plese see file on above

Answer (score 1):

Add this library in your dependencies too

```
compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
```

Comment: @OsanKumarSingh sorry about that.. same line solved my problem. did you clean and rebuild after adding this ??

Comment: After clean and rebuild                                             
 Information:Gradle tasks [clean, :app:assembleDebug]
Error:Error converting bytecode to dex:
Cause: com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Lokio/Segment;
Error:com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Lokio/Segment;
Error: at

Comment: can you try one  last thing.. Goto build -- make project and check @OsanKumarSingh