# Unable to install app on EMULATOR and to launch it - React Native

Tags: react-native

**Please I am a beginner in reactNative and i tried to creat an application using emulator and the command react-native run-android and this is what gone. Please help me**

Description:

info Running jetifier to migrate libraries to AndroidX. You can disable it using "--no-jetifier" flag.
Jetifier found 864 file(s) to forward-jetify. Using 4 workers...
info Starting JS server...
* daemon not running; starting now at tcp:5037
* daemon started successfully
info Installing the app...
Starting a Gradle Daemon, 1 incompatible and 3 stopped Daemons could not be reused, use --status for details

> Task :app:transformClassesWithDexBuilderForDebug FAILED

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 6.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/5.5/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings
17 actionable tasks: 8 executed, 9 up-to-date

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexBuilderForDebug'.

  > Could not read path 'C:\Users\ruthel BAC\Desktop\firstAppReact\android\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\96\androidx\customview'.
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1m 39s

error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html#android-development-environment. Run CLI 
with --verbose flag for more details.
Error: Command failed: gradlew.bat app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexBuilderForDebug'.

  > Could not read path 'C:\Users\ruthel BAC\Desktop\firstAppReact\android\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\96\androidx\customview'.
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1m 39s

```
at checkExecSyncError (child_process.js:616:11)
at execFileSync (child_process.js:634:13)
at runOnAllDevices (C:\Users\ruthel BAC\Desktop\firstAppReact\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\build\commands\runAndroid\runOnAllDevices.js:94:39)
at buildAndRun (C:\Users\ruthel BAC\Desktop\firstAppReact\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\build\commands\runAndroid\index.js:179:41)
at then.result (C:\Users\ruthel BAC\Desktop\firstAppReact\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\build\commands\runAndroid\index.js:133:12)
at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
```

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! firstAppReact@0.0.1 android: `react-native run-android`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the firstAppReact@0.0.1 android script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\nodejs\npm-cache_logs\2020-02-28T09_11_15_219Z-debug.log

Comment: possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35890257/android-errorexecution-failed-for-task-apptransformclasseswithdexforrelease

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Cancel the process
- Open new terminal
- In your project directory, run
- `cd android` --> `.\gradlew clean`
- After finishing that, `cd..` so that you can direct to the project file
- Run `react-native-start`
- Wait for the terminal shows: `Looking for dependency, done`
- Then open the second terminal, direct to your project and run `react-native run-android` (or ios if you're using Xcode)
  I ran into this problem before so try this. Hope it'd help you

Comment: the solution was to run the emulator without run android studio before

Comment: follow the link to see more: https://windowsloop.com/launch-avd-manager-without-android-studio/