# I cant build after upgrading to Facebook unity sdk -11 and build fails at gradle stage

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, facebook-unity-sdk

After trying to upgrade to the Facebook unity sdk version:11.0.0 the build always fails at the gradle stage i use unity 2018.3.71 , i removed all the older version files and imported the new sdk files and i keep getting this errors when building, can anyone direct me in the way to  fix this ?
Things i have tried :
1- use proguard file
2- removing some files from the sdk that can cause conflicts
3- delete the manifest file

```html
CommandInvokationFailure: Gradle build failed. 
C:\Program Files\Unity\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer/Tools\OpenJDK\Windows\bin\java.exe -classpath "C:\Program Files\Unity\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\Tools\gradle\lib\gradle-launcher-4.6.jar" org.gradle.launcher.GradleMain "-Dorg.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx4096m" "assembleRelease"

stderr[
error processing C:\My stuff\Projects\bltq_UniProj\Temp\gradleOut\libs\org.jetbrains.kotlin.kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.4.10.jar
java.lang.RuntimeException
    at org.objectweb.asm.ClassVisitor.visitModule(ClassVisitor.java:148)
    at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.readModule(ClassReader.java:731)
    at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.accept(ClassReader.java:632)
    at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.accept(ClassReader.java:500)
    at com.android.builder.desugaring.DesugaringClassAnalyzer.analyze(DesugaringClassAnalyzer.java:144)
    at com.android.builder.desugaring.DesugaringClassAnalyzer.analyzeJar(DesugaringClassAnalyzer.java:92)
    at com.android.builder.desugaring.DesugaringClassAnalyzer.analyze(DesugaringClassAnalyzer.java:63)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.DesugarIncrementalTransformHelper.lambda$getInitalGraphData$4(DesugarIncrementalTransformHelper.java:150)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask$AdaptedCallable.exec(ForkJoinTask.java:1424)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:289)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1056)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1692)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:157)
error processing C:\My stuff\Projects\bltq_UniProj\Temp\gradleOut\libs\org.jetbrains.kotlin.kotlin-stdlib-1.4.10.jar
java.lang.RuntimeException
    at org.objectweb.asm.ClassVisitor.visitModule(ClassVisitor.java:148)
    at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.readModule(ClassReader.java:731)
    at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.accept(ClassReader.java:632)
    at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.accept(ClassReader.java:500)
    at com.android.builder.desugaring.DesugaringClassAnalyzer.analyze(DesugaringClassAnalyzer.java:144)
    at com.android.builder.desugaring.DesugaringClassAnalyzer.analyzeJar(DesugaringClassAnalyzer.java:92)
    at com.android.builder.desugaring.DesugaringClassAnalyzer.analyze(DesugaringClassAnalyzer.java:63)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.DesugarIncrementalTransformHelper.lambda$getInitalGraphData$4(DesugarIncrementalTransformHelper.java:150)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask$AdaptedCallable.exec(ForkJoinTask.java:1424)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:289)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1056)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1692)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:157)
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.getThrowableException(ForkJoinTask.java:593)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.reportException(ForkJoinTask.java:677)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.join(ForkJoinTask.java:720)
    at com.android.ide.common.internal.WaitableExecutor.waitForTasksWithQuickFail(WaitableExecutor.java:146)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.DesugarIncrementalTransformHelper.getInitalGraphData(DesugarIncrementalTransformHelper.java:162)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.DesugarIncrementalTransformHelper.makeDesugaringGraph(DesugarIncrementalTransformHelper.java:130)
    at com.google.common.base.Suppliers$NonSerializableMemoizingSupplier.get(Suppliers.java:160)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.DesugarIncrementalTransformHelper.getDependenciesPaths(DesugarIncrementalTransformHelper.java:231)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.DexArchiveBuilderTransform.getD8DesugaringCacheInfo(DexArchiveBuilderTransform.java:461)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.DexArchiveBuilderTransform.transform(DexArchiveBuilderTransform.java:375)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.pipeline.TransformTask$2.call(TransformTask.java:239)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.pipeline.TransformTask$2.call(TransformTask.java:235)
    at com.android.builder.profile.ThreadRecorder.record(ThreadRecorder.java:102)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.pipeline.TransformTask.transform(TransformTask.java:230)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:73)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.IncrementalTaskAction.doExecute(IncrementalTaskAction.java:50)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:39)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:26)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$1.run(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:124)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:199)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:110)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:113)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:95)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:73)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.OutputDirectoryCreatingTaskExecuter.execute(OutputDirectoryCreatingTaskExecuter.java:51)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:59)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.java:54)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:59)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:101)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.FinalizeInputFilePropertiesTaskExecuter.execute(FinalizeInputFilePropertiesTaskExecuter.java:44)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.execute(CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.java:91)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.java:62)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:59)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:54)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:34)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker$1.run(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:256)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:199)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:110)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:249)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:238)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.processTask(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:123)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.access$200(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:79)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:104)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:98)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.java:663)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.executeWithTask(DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.java:597)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:98)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException
    at org.objectweb.asm.ClassVisitor.visitModule(ClassVisitor.java:148)
    at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.readModule(ClassReader.java:731)
    at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.accept(ClassReader.java:632)
    at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.accept(ClassReader.java:500)
    at com.android.builder.desugaring.DesugaringClassAnalyzer.analyze(DesugaringClassAnalyzer.java:144)
    at com.android.builder.desugaring.DesugaringClassAnalyzer.analyzeJar(DesugaringClassAnalyzer.java:92)
    at com.android.builder.desugaring.DesugaringClassAnalyzer.analyze(DesugaringClassAnalyzer.java:63)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.DesugarIncrementalTransformHelper.lambda$getInitalGraphData$4(DesugarIncrementalTransformHelper.java:150)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask$AdaptedCallable.exec(ForkJoinTask.java:1424)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:289)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1056)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1692)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:157)


FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':transformClassesWithDexBuilderForRelease'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 10s
]
stdout[
:checkReleaseClasspath
:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:Firebase:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:Firebase:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:Firebase:checkReleaseManifest
:Firebase:processReleaseManifest
:unity-android-resources:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:unity-android-resources:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:unity-android-resources:checkReleaseManifest
:unity-android-resources:processReleaseManifest
:preReleaseBuild
:Firebase:compileReleaseAidl NO-SOURCE
:unity-android-resources:compileReleaseAidl NO-SOURCE
:compileReleaseAidl NO-SOURCE
:Firebase:packageReleaseRenderscript NO-SOURCE
:unity-android-resources:packageReleaseRenderscript NO-SOURCE
:compileReleaseRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:checkReleaseManifest UP-TO-DATE
:generateReleaseBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:prepareLintJar UP-TO-DATE
:mainApkListPersistenceRelease UP-TO-DATE
:generateReleaseResValues UP-TO-DATE
:generateReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
:Firebase:compileReleaseRenderscript
:Firebase:generateReleaseResValues
:Firebase:generateReleaseResources
:Firebase:packageReleaseResources
:unity-android-resources:compileReleaseRenderscript
:unity-android-resources:generateReleaseResValues
:unity-android-resources:generateReleaseResources
:unity-android-resources:packageReleaseResources
:mergeReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
:createReleaseCompatibleScreenManifests UP-TO-DATE
:processReleaseManifest
:splitsDiscoveryTaskRelease UP-TO-DATE
:Firebase:generateReleaseRFile
:unity-android-resources:generateReleaseRFile
:processReleaseResources
:generateReleaseSources
:Firebase:generateReleaseBuildConfig
:Firebase:prepareLintJar UP-TO-DATE
:Firebase:generateReleaseSources
:Firebase:javaPreCompileRelease
:Firebase:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac
:Firebase:processReleaseJavaRes NO-SOURCE
:Firebase:transformClassesAndResourcesWithPrepareIntermediateJarsForRelease
:unity-android-resources:generateReleaseBuildConfig
:unity-android-resources:prepareLintJar UP-TO-DATE
:unity-android-resources:generateReleaseSources
:unity-android-resources:javaPreCompileRelease
:unity-android-resources:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac
:unity-android-resources:processReleaseJavaRes NO-SOURCE
:unity-android-resources:transformClassesAndResourcesWithPrepareIntermediateJarsForRelease
:javaPreCompileRelease
:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac
:compileReleaseNdk NO-SOURCE
:compileReleaseSources
:lintVitalRelease
:mergeReleaseShaders UP-TO-DATE
:compileReleaseShaders UP-TO-DATE
:generateReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE
:Firebase:mergeReleaseShaders
:Firebase:compileReleaseShaders
:Firebase:generateReleaseAssets
:Firebase:packageReleaseAssets
:unity-android-resources:mergeReleaseShaders
:unity-android-resources:compileReleaseShaders
:unity-android-resources:generateReleaseAssets
:unity-android-resources:packageReleaseAssets
:mergeReleaseAssets
:transformClassesWithDexBuilderForRelease FAILED
48 actionable tasks: 35 executed, 13 up-to-date
]
exit code: 1
UnityEditor.Android.Command.WaitForProgramToRun (UnityEditor.Utils.Program p, UnityEditor.Android.Command+WaitingForProcessToExit waitingForProcessToExit, System.String errorMsg) (at <76abbd884b37447da464288ec1125ab8>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.Command.Run (System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo psi, UnityEditor.Android.Command+WaitingForProcessToExit waitingForProcessToExit, System.String errorMsg) (at <76abbd884b37447da464288ec1125ab8>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.Command.Run (System.String command, System.String args, System.String workingdir, UnityEditor.Android.Command+WaitingForProcessToExit waitingForProcessToExit, System.String errorMsg) (at <76abbd884b37447da464288ec1125ab8>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.AndroidJavaTools.RunJava (System.String args, System.String workingdir, System.Action`1[T] progress, System.String error) (at <76abbd884b37447da464288ec1125ab8>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.GradleWrapper.Run (UnityEditor.Android.AndroidJavaTools javaTools, System.String workingdir, System.String task, System.Action`1[T] progress) (at <76abbd884b37447da464288ec1125ab8>:0)
Rethrow as GradleInvokationException: Gradle build failed
UnityEditor.Android.GradleWrapper.Run (UnityEditor.Android.AndroidJavaTools javaTools, System.String workingdir, System.String task, System.Action`1[T] progress) (at <76abbd884b37447da464288ec1125ab8>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.Tasks.BuildGradleProject.Execute (UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessorContext context) (at <76abbd884b37447da464288ec1125ab8>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessRunner.RunAllTasks (UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessorContext context) (at <76abbd884b37447da464288ec1125ab8>:0)
UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr)
```

Comment: check [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35890257/android-errorexecution-failed-for-task-apptransformclasseswithdexforrelease) you will find your answer. just use multidex

Comment: @Jaimin i tried didnt work

Answer (score 0):

You have to change version of Android Gradle plugin to **3.6.0**.

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.6.0' in mainTemplate.gradle
```

But version of Gradle tool installed (embedded) with Unity 2018.3.71 **is not compatible** with plugin 3.6.0. So you have to export project and build it in Android Studio, or update Unity to latest 2018.4 LTS and use external Gradle tool (version 5.6.4) like described here: https://developers.google.com/ar/develop/unity/android-11-build?hl=en