# Gradle build failed: Dex files cannot exceed 64k

Tags: java, android, gradle, dalvik, dex

Whenever I build by project and prepare for launch on my device, I keep getting this error:

> Error:The number of method references in a .dex file cannot exceed 64K.
>   Learn how to resolve this issue at https://developer.android.com/tools/building/multidex.html

Additionally, I get this error:

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.
>   com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_91\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 2

And it says gradle build failed with two errors

So I have some questions:

- What are dex files
- I'm not using them directly, so why do I get the errors above?
- What are in dex files?
- Do these files have anything to say for the .APK file size?

These errors started appearing again after I stopped using proguard for debug builds as the StackTrace did not show and right before I activated proguard I had the error.

I had this error once before and I deleted the dex folder and it solved it but now it suddenly isn't enough anymore.

my gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.myproject"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23

    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            shrinkResources true

            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }

    }
}

dependencies {

    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.0-alpha1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.3.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:9.2.0'
}
```

Comment: You should **never** use the full `play-services` dependency. Only use the [select Play services APIs you need](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup#split). Including the entire thing is 45k+ of the 64k method limit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The more dependencies you add - the higher your method count. Change your gradle to reflect this:

```
defaultConfig {
    ...
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 23
    ...

    // Enabling multidex support.
    multiDexEnabled true
}
```

This is a straight forward fix, and only works if you minSdkVerison is 14 or above. 
Also add the following dependency:

```
dependencies {
  compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
}
```

Sometimes, the dependencies which you leverage will (individually) reference the same libraries - you may have many methods which are doubled, tripled, quadruple, etc... Check out this SO answer to resolve this and always reduce your APK size. 
[gradle - library duplicates in dependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30648172/gradle-library-duplicates-in-dependencies)

Comment: Does it at all affect the size of the APK?

Comment: Read the article in the error message in full - it is all very insightful! To answer this comment though: https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex.html#dev-build

Comment: FWIW, you can *never* have multiple dependencies in your app from the same library - they are always deduped by Gradle.

Answer (score 1):

**From Google documentation :**

> Android application (APK) files contain executable bytecode files in
>   the form of Dalvik Executable (DEX) files, which contain the compiled
>   code used to run your app. The Dalvik Executable specification limits
>   the total number of methods that can be referenced within a single DEX
>   file to 65,536—including Android framework methods, library methods,
>   and methods in your own code.

To solve this you need to make following changes in your code :

build.gradle

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.0"

    defaultConfig {
        ...
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 21
        ...

        // Enabling multidex support.
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    ...
}

dependencies {
  compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
}
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.android.multidex.myapplication">
    <application
        ...
        android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication">
        ...
    </application>
</manifest>
```

> When these configuration settings are added to an app, the Android
>   build tools construct a primary dex (classes.dex) and supporting
>   (classes2.dex, classes3.dex) as needed. The build system will then
>   package them into an APK file for distribution.

**Please note :** If you already have class in your code which extends from Application class then just change it to extend from MultidexApplication.

Answer (score 0):

The playservices lib is quite huge. Even a tiny app may suffer from that problem. After using the Proguard the problem will disappear due to the optimizations removing unused stuff. For development (debug builds) - limiting libs only to what you're really using usually helps. You can try narrowing the library or/and use 'exclude' filter in the compile() gradle statement.

For example, when I needed it for the location services, I've used:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.2.0'
```

at first and got that message. Replaced it with the

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:10.2.0'
```

and got it resolved gracefully.