# RecyclerView-v7:24.2.0 causing ZipException

Tags: java, android, gradle, android-recyclerview

I'm trying to use the new DiffUtil class that was introduced in recyclerview-v7:24.2.0.

However, I've discovered that updating my dependencies in my build.gradle makes it so that I can no longer run my app.

Below is my current list of dependencies which **will build**:

```
dependencies {
  compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')

  compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:24.1.1'

  compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
  compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:24.2.0'
  androidTestCompile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:24.2.0'
  androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2'
  androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:runner:0.5'
  compile 'com.github.siyamed:android-shape-imageview:0.9.3@aar'
  compile 'com.neovisionaries:nv-websocket-client:1.12'
  compile 'com.nightonke:jellytogglebutton:1.0.2'
  compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.4.0-RC1'
  compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
  compile 'de.greenrobot:eventbus:2.4.0'
  compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.0.0'
  compile('com.github.ozodrukh:CircularReveal:1.3.1@aar') {
    transitive = true;
  }
  compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.1.0'
  apt 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.1.0'
  compile 'io.reactivex:rxandroid:1.2.1'
  compile 'io.reactivex:rxjava:1.1.6'
  compile "com.github.fge:json-patch:1.9"
  apt 'com.squareup:javapoet:1.7.0'
  apt 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.2'
  compile 'com.google.dagger:dagger:2.2'
  provided 'javax.annotation:jsr250-api:1.0'
  compile 'com.github.pwittchen:reactivenetwork:0.5.0'
  testCompile "junit:junit:4.12"
  testCompile "org.mockito:mockito-all:1.10.19"
  compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.6.2@aar') {
    transitive = true;
  }
  debugCompile 'com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android:1.4-beta2'
  releaseCompile 'com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android-no-op:1.4-beta2'
  testCompile 'com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android-no-op:1.4-beta2'
}
```

All I do is change the one version number from **24.1.1** to **24.2.0** like so:

```
dependencies {
  compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')

  compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:24.2.0'

  compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
  compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:24.2.0'
  androidTestCompile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:24.2.0'
  androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2'
  androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:runner:0.5'
  compile 'com.github.siyamed:android-shape-imageview:0.9.3@aar'
  compile 'com.neovisionaries:nv-websocket-client:1.12'
  compile 'com.nightonke:jellytogglebutton:1.0.2'
  compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.4.0-RC1'
  compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
  compile 'de.greenrobot:eventbus:2.4.0'
  compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.0.0'
  compile('com.github.ozodrukh:CircularReveal:1.3.1@aar') {
    transitive = true;
  }
  compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.1.0'
  apt 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.1.0'
  compile 'io.reactivex:rxandroid:1.2.1'
  compile 'io.reactivex:rxjava:1.1.6'
  compile "com.github.fge:json-patch:1.9"
  apt 'com.squareup:javapoet:1.7.0'
  apt 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.2'
  compile 'com.google.dagger:dagger:2.2'
  provided 'javax.annotation:jsr250-api:1.0'
  compile 'com.github.pwittchen:reactivenetwork:0.5.0'
  testCompile "junit:junit:4.12"
  testCompile "org.mockito:mockito-all:1.10.19"
  compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.6.2@aar') {
    transitive = true;
  }
  debugCompile 'com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android:1.4-beta2'
  releaseCompile 'com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android-no-op:1.4-beta2'
  testCompile 'com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android-no-op:1.4-beta2'
}
```

If I make this change, my build fails with the following error:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: android/support/v4/view/PagerTitleStrip$PageListener.class
```

I've tried setting up various exclusions for support modules, and I've tried using different prefixes for compilation (like androidTestCompile vs compile).

If anyone could make sense if what's going on and help me out, I'd be eternally grateful. Thanks.

Comment: just add the v4 support line in gradle and you will be fine

Comment: BTW, I recommend you update the version of nv-websocket-client to the latest one for some bugfixes. The version 1.12 is too old.

Answer (score 1):

add this to `build.gradle` file , you have duplicate dependency so this will exclude the collision

```
configurations {
    all*.exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-v4'
}
```

if above don't work then you can simply do

```
compile ('com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:+') {
    exclude module: 'support-v4'
}
```

Comment: If I do this, then I can't use anything from the support-v4 library, and I have code that still relies on that library.

Comment: no man , this will remove it from other during build but keep the original one

Comment: I tried adding it like this:
https://gist.github.com/aaronjstar/46ad64c99ea9f305c7279255d35cc805

But this removed it from everything. How should I add it?

Comment: put it outside of dependency block, any-where

Comment: If I do that, I can't build anymore. Anything that's part of the support-v4 library can't be found anymore

Comment: you can try the updated answer to remove it form particular module

Comment: When I try the new answer I still have the same exception:
`Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: android/support/v4/view/PagerTitleStrip$PageListener.class`

Comment: try the gradle dependency view to find duplicate dependency using studio,steps :  https://developer.android.com/studio/build/build-variants.html  then use exclude command for every duplicate one for this try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30648172/gradle-library-duplicates-in-dependencies

Answer (score 0):

Clean and Rebuild the project in Android Studio or via gradle command.

Command in gradle to do so
`./gradlew clean`

Comment: Even after cleaning and rebuilding, I still have the same problem.