# Run time gradle exception

Tags: android, android-studio

I know this is a repeated question but I tried numerous code but couldn't solve the error

> ```
> Error:Execution failed for task
> ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry:
> android/support/v4/accessibilityservice/AccessibilityServiceInfoCompat$AccessibilityServiceInfoVersionImpl.class
> ```

**gradle file**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
  compileSdkVersion 23
  buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"

  defaultConfig {
      applicationId "com.cwish"
      minSdkVersion 16
      targetSdkVersion 23
      versionCode 1
      versionName "1.0"
      multiDexEnabled true
  }
  buildTypes {
      release {
          minifyEnabled false
          proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
      }
  }
}
dependencies {

  compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
  testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
  compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
  compile 'com.android.support:design:23.4.0'
  compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.6.2'
  compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.1.0'
  compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.1.0'
  compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:+'
  compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.1.0@aar'
  compile 'com.daimajia.numberprogressbar:library:1.2@aar'
  compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.3.0'
  compile 'com.koushikdutta.ion:ion:2.+'
}
```

Comment: Can you add your gradle file?

Comment: i added gradle file above

Comment: @ErKishorMaharjan you are using support:recyclerview-v7 two time. Just remove compile `'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.1.0@aar'` from your gradle it will solve your problem :)

Comment: @HarinKaklotar removing complie coudnt solve the problem is there any other solution...

Comment: Do you have added any other libs under the 'libs' directory?

Answer (score 4):

I guess this problem can be resolved by removing duplicate dependencies,before removing the duplicate dependencies, you should check your modules by this command:

```
gradlew -q dependencies yourProject:dependencies --configuration compile
```

refer to this answer:[duplicate dependencies problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30648172/gradle-library-duplicates-in-dependencies)

Hope it can help you :)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like duplicate dependency problem, remove "compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.1.0@aar" and it'll be fine.