# TransformException: duplicate entry: org/kaazing/gateway/client/transport/AuthenticateEvent.class

Tags: android, build.gradle

I am getting this error after selecting "Build Apk" in android studio.

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'.

> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: org/kaazing/gateway/client/transport/AuthenticateEvent.class

these are the dependencies i have included:

```
 dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:8.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.facebook.stetho:stetho:1.3.1'
    compile 'solar.blaz:week-date-picker:1.1'
    compile 'com.p_v:flexiblecalendar:1.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.theartofdev.edmodo:android-image-cropper:2.2.5'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    compile 'com.github.stfalcon:frescoimageviewer:0.2.0'
    compile 'com.facebook.fresco:fresco:0.13.0'
    compile files('libs/httpmime-4.3.jar')
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.1.0'
    compile 'com.koushikdutta.ion:ion:2.1.9'
    compile 'com.jaredrummler:material-spinner:1.1.0'
    compile 'org.kaazing:gateway.client.java:5.1.0.4'
}
```

I tried to find dependencies duplicates from [gradle - library duplicates in dependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30648172/gradle-library-duplicates-in-dependencies) and there are no overlaps for org.kaazing

```
+--- com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0
|    +--- com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:23.4.0
|    |    \--- com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:23.4.0
|    |         \--- com.android.support:support-v4:23.4.0
|    |              \--- com.android.support:support-annotations:23.4.0 -> 24.1.1
|    +--- com.android.support:support-v4:23.4.0 (*)
|    \--- com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:23.4.0 (*)
+--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:8.4.0
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:8.4.0
|    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:8.4.0
|    |         \--- com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.0 -> 23.4.0 (*)
|    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement:8.4.0
|         \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:8.4.0 (*)
+--- com.android.support:design:23.4.0
|    +--- com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.4.0
|    |    +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:23.4.0 -> 24.1.1
|    |    \--- com.android.support:support-v4:23.4.0 (*)
|    +--- com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0 (*)
|    \--- com.android.support:support-v4:23.4.0 (*)
+--- com.facebook.stetho:stetho:1.3.1
|    +--- com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:2.0.1
|    \--- commons-cli:commons-cli:1.2
+--- solar.blaz:week-date-picker:1.1
|    +--- com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1 -> 23.4.0 (*)
|    \--- org.threeten:threetenbp:1.3.1
+--- com.p_v:flexiblecalendar:1.2.1
+--- com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.4.0 (*)
+--- com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.4.0
+--- com.android.support:support-v4:23.4.0 (*)
+--- com.theartofdev.edmodo:android-image-cropper:2.2.5
|    \--- com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.1 -> 23.4.0 (*)
+--- com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2
+--- com.github.stfalcon:frescoimageviewer:0.2.0
|    +--- com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0 (*)
|    \--- me.relex:photodraweeview:1.1.0
+--- com.facebook.fresco:fresco:0.13.0
|    +--- com.facebook.fresco:drawee:0.13.0
|    |    +--- com.android.support:support-v4:23.2.1 -> 23.4.0 (*)
|    |    \--- com.facebook.fresco:fbcore:0.13.0
|    +--- com.facebook.fresco:fbcore:0.13.0
|    \--- com.facebook.fresco:imagepipeline:0.13.0
|         +--- com.android.support:support-v4:23.2.1 -> 23.4.0 (*)
|         +--- com.facebook.fresco:imagepipeline-base:0.13.0
|         |    +--- com.android.support:support-v4:23.2.1 -> 23.4.0 (*)
|         |    +--- com.parse.bolts:bolts-tasks:1.4.0
|         |    \--- com.facebook.fresco:fbcore:0.13.0
|         +--- com.parse.bolts:bolts-tasks:1.4.0
|         \--- com.facebook.fresco:fbcore:0.13.0
+--- com.koushikdutta.ion:ion:2.1.9
|    +--- com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3
|    \--- com.koushikdutta.async:androidasync:2.1.9
+--- com.jaredrummler:material-spinner:1.1.0
|    \--- com.android.support:support-annotations:24.1.1
+--- org.kaazing:gateway.client.java:5.1.0.4
|    +--- org.kaazing:gateway.client.java.transport:5.1.0.4
|    |    \--- org.jmock:jmock-junit4:2.6.0
|    |         +--- org.jmock:jmock:2.6.0
|    |         |    +--- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:1.1
|    |         |    \--- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-library:1.1
|    |         |         \--- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:1.1
|    |         \--- junit:junit-dep:4.4
|    \--- org.kaazing:net.api:5.1.0.4
\--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement:8.4.0 (*)
```

Can anyone help me with this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It means that `org/kaazing/gateway/client/transport/AuthenticateEvent.class` is not only in  `org.kaazing:gateway.client.java:5.1.0.4` but as well in some other dependency.  For finding which library is using the same please refer to this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30648172/gradle-library-duplicates-in-dependencies

Comment: Which API did you add recently? @jakubbialkowski

Comment: @jakubbialkowski, do you have the following in your gradle file:      compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')

Comment: @ParthaChakraborty you are asking the wrong guy :) I added a comment, not posted the question :)

Comment: @jakubbialkowski, oops! my bad

Answer (score 0):

just remove

```
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
```

in gradle file

It works for me ..