# Error get Font Landroid/content/Context;ILandroid/util/TypedValue

Tags: java, android

I have problem with my project. I don't know how to fix it. This is first time I meet it.

> /UncaughtException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No static method
>   getFont(Landroid/content/Context;ILandroid/util/TypedValue;ILandroid/widget/TextView;)Landroid/graphics/Typeface;
>   in class Landroid/support/v4/content/res/ResourcesCompat; or its super
>   classes (declaration of
>   'android.support.v4.content.res.ResourcesCompat' appears in
>   /data/app/codes.trongtin.h.besttrip-2/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk:classes2.dex)

Comment: Probably, you are using wrong version of the library.

Comment: Me too facing same issue today I updated my android studio from then onwards I'm facing the problem

Comment: Had this same problem after moving to v27 of support library...doing a clean build fixed the issue for me.

Comment: This solution is work for me. Click Here.[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30649660/7377680)

Answer (score 21):

It seems you are using support dependencies.
Just check in your app gradle that your build tools version is the same as support versions.

For example:

```
android {
...
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.2"
...
}
```

and

```
dependencies {
...
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v13:26.0.2'
...
}
```

must have the same version.

It worked for me!

Answer (score 6):

Just Change complieSdkVersion, buildToolsVersion and appCompat dependency.

```
      compileSdkVersion 27
      buildToolsVersion '27.0.0'

      implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.2'
```

Answer (score 3):

Thanks @agustin-ruiz-linares for the correct answer.

I'll add my setup here along with the Firebase and Glide libraries that I'm using in case its helpful for someone. I was seeing the error until I reconciled the library versions along with the buildToolsVersion and targetSdkVersions, too.

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 20
        targetSdkVersion 27
        buildToolsVersion "27.0.2"
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.8.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:11.8.0'
    implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:3.2.1'
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.5.0'
    annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.5.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.0.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
}
```

Comment: This was the correct answer for me. 26.0.2 Did not work, but moving every dependencie to the 27.0.2 fixed all the bugs.

Answer (score 1):

This error happen if there is a mismatch in version of any support dependency .
2 things to consider to avoid this error:

1. Make sure you are using the Latest version of  compileSdkVersion 27
2. ALL the support libraries should be of exactly same version

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using support library, Use ResourcesCompat

```
Typeface typeFace= ResourcesCompat.getFont(getActivity(),R.font.roboto);
```

This will fix your problem.

If you want to support api level 26 and above you can use

```
Typeface typeface = getResources().getFont(R.font.myfont);
```

Comment: For me it showing issue in xml layout simply setContentView(R.layout.main). if I removed Textview from the layout its not showing any issues and working fine. But I need Textview how can I resolve this

Comment: are you using android studio 3.0 ?

Comment: In my case I am using version 27.0.2. And still occurs

Comment: @Godwin make sure you are using studio 3.0 or up

Answer (score -1):

The solution is very simple ..just change build tool version to 27.0.2 and all supports library to 27.0.2

Done.
Bingo!