# How to exclude certain part of a gradle dependecy?

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, gcloud

Multiple dependencies has similar named class and I'm getting duplicate class errors. To solve I think excluding those parts may help. How to exclude these parts?

Errors +lots of similar lines:

```
Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.AbstractMessageLite found in modules protobuf-java-3.7.1.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-java:3.7.1) and protobuf-lite-3.0.1.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.AbstractMessageLite$Builder found in modules protobuf-java-3.7.1.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-java:3.7.1) and protobuf-lite-3.0.1.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.AbstractMessageLite$Builder$LimitedInputStream found in modules protobuf-java-3.7.1.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-java:3.7.1) and protobuf-lite-3.0.1.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
```

Dependencies:

```
// gRPC
    implementation "io.grpc:grpc-okhttp:$grpcVersion"
    implementation "io.grpc:grpc-protobuf-lite:$grpcVersion"
    implementation "io.grpc:grpc-stub:$grpcVersion"
    implementation 'javax.annotation:javax.annotation-api:1.3.2'
    //protobuf 'com.google.protobuf:protobuf-java:3.8.0'//error persist with this and without this

    // OAuth2 for Google API
    implementation('com.google.auth:google-auth-library-oauth2-http:0.7.0') {
        exclude module: 'httpclient'
    }

    //Translation
    implementation "com.google.cloud:google-cloud-translate:$grpcVersion"
    implementation('com.google.cloud:google-cloud-translate:1.79.0') {
        exclude group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents'
        exclude group: 'org.json', module: 'json'

//I want to exclude error classes here...HOW?...
        //exclude group: 'com.google.protobuf', module: 'protobuf-java-3.7.1'
    }
    annotationProcessor "com.google.cloud:google-cloud-translate:$grpcVersion"
```

grpc version on ext:

```
grpcVersion = '1.4.0'
```

these are not related to support library versions as these are because of **translation and protobuf-lite** libraries. these are using different versions of those class and I dont know if excluding of them will work or not.

Is it possible to extract those libraries and change those class names?
I want to see if excluding those classes can solve it. How to exclude?

Comment: Check this out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30648172/gradle-library-duplicates-in-dependencies

Comment: I need to know what to exclude from the error logs. As you see that I'm trying to exclude the part shown on error but it doesn't work. That answer basically states to exclude something but how can I extract what is the right module name. The module name is there but how to make that name exact?