# Gradle duplicate libraries not omitted

Tags: android, gradle

Here is the result when I run `./gradlew app:dependencies`:

```
+--- com.android.volley:volley:1.1.1
+--- com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828
|    +--- com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.10.0
|    |    \--- com.squareup.okio:okio:1.14.0
|    +--- androidx.annotation:annotation:1.0.0 -> 1.1.0
|    \--- androidx.exifinterface:exifinterface:1.0.0
|         \--- androidx.annotation:annotation:1.0.0 -> 1.1.0
\--- com.myapp:commonlib:1.0.2
     +--- com.android.volley:volley:1.1.1
     \--- com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828 (*)

(*) - dependencies omitted (listed previously)
```

The last line indicates that `picasso:2.71828` has been omitted since it appeared before.

My questions are:

1. `volley:1.1.1` (the second-last line) also appeared before on line 1, why didn't it be omitted (no (*) in the end of that line)?
2. Will the duplicate libraries increase the APK size?

Thanks.

Comment: Please read this, Hope it'll help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30648172/gradle-library-duplicates-in-dependencies

Answer (score 0):

1. The duplicate libraries will increase the Apk size since they are all packaged by gradle while building the final APK or app bundle
2. The dependencies will not be omitted because they are coming from two different libraries and no rule has been specified to omit them.
3. You can exclude the duplicate libs manually by gradle options

   Exclude dependencies from your build.gradle file

```
     dependencies {
           implementation('some-library') {
            exclude group: 'com.example.imgtools', module: 'native'
           }
        }
```

Comment: What's the difference between `picasso` and `volley`? One of them is omitted, but not the other.

Comment: Check those libraries gradle rules, as to how are packaged in an .aar.