# How to group multiple dependency in same line - Gradle

Tags: java, gradle

In the following example, I have 3 dependencies with the same group and the same version. I want to group these three dependencies in **one line**.

```
compile group: 'org.apache.ws.commons.axiom', name: 'axiom-api', version: '1.2.7'
compile group: 'org.apache.ws.commons.axiom', name: 'axiom-dom', version: '1.2.7'
compile group: 'org.apache.ws.commons.axiom', name: 'axiom-impl', version: '1.2.7'
```

Expected like below

```
group("axiom-api", "axiom-dom", "axiom-impl", :under=>"org.apache.ws.commons.axiom", :version=>"1.2.7")
```

Is it possible in `gradle`?

Comment: Could you provide an example of how you expect it to look like? I don't see no point in formatting it in one line. You could/should however use a variable for the version number to keep the versions always in sync.

Comment: @dpr I have updated my question with my expectation.

Comment: As you have same version, to find the optimum, try this useful suggestion  https://stackoverflow.com/a/30649660/13031115

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well it's actually more lines in total, but if this (same group, same version and multiple artifacts) is a repeating pattern, it might still be handy:

```
def groupDependencies ( group, names, version ) {
  def deps = []
  names.each { it -> 
    deps += [group: group, name: it, version: version]
  }

  return deps
}

dependencies {
  compile(groupDependencies('org.apache.ws.commons.axiom', ['axiom-api', 'axiom-dom', 'axiom-impl'], '1.2.7'))
}
```

Comment: the above code not working. it does not throw an error and the same time did not download the dependencies.

Comment: @Shakthifuture, tested with gradle 6.4.1 and it works. What version of gradle are you using?

Comment: I am using 6.0 Gradle version.

Comment: @Shakthifuture could you try a more recent version?

Comment: 6.0 is not a very old version, see https://gradle.org/releases/

Comment: @Shakthifuture So are you trying a more recent version?

Comment: @Shakthifuture, see my update. I tested with gradle 6.0 myself and it works pretty well.

Answer (score 0):

This is an example where you can add different artifacts each with a different version.

```
def groupDependencies (group, artifact) {
    def dependencies = []

    artifact.each { it ->
        dependencies += [group: group, name: it["name"], version: it["version"]]
    }

    return dependencies
}

dependencies {
    implementation(groupDependencies("org.apache.commons", [
            [name: "commons-lang3", version: "3.12.0"],
            [name: "commons-collections4", version: "4.4"],
            [name: "commons-compress", version: "1.21"]
    ]))
}
```

And this other is for when the group and the name is the same (you can use them both on the same file):

```
def groupDependencies (artifact) {
    def dependencies = []

    artifact.each { it ->
        dependencies += [group: it["name"], name: it["name"], version: it["version"]]
    }

    return dependencies
}

dependencies {
    implementation(groupDependencies([
            [name: "commons-cli", version: "1.5.0"],
            [name: "commons-io", version: "2.11.0"]
    ]))
}
```